# How do I add this jQuery into my Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, algorithm

Currently learning jQuery right now and want to use FadeOut and FadeIn everytime some add or delete on my to do list. I know I can use CSS for this, but I am learning jQuery right now.

```
function showList(){
  container.innerHTML = "";
  get().forEach((value, index) => {
    var li = document.createElement("div");
    li.id = index;
    li.className = "list";
    li.innerHTML = `
      <span id="${index}" onclick="checked(${index})">${value}</span>
      <i onclick="deleteTodo(${index})" class="iconclick fa fa-trash"></i>
      <i onclick="editTodo(${index})" class="iconclick fa fa-edit"></i>
    `;
    li.classList.add("listClass");
    container.appendChild(li);
  });
}



function addButton(){
  //check and see if the input is blank
  const todos = get();

  if(input.value === ""){
    input.placeholder = "Please enter something";
  } else{
    todos.push(input.value);
    set(todos);
    showList();
    input.value = "";
  }
}

function deleteTodo(index){
  const todos = get();
  todos.forEach((value, index) => {
    console.log("index", index)
    console.log("value", value)
    $(`#${index}`).click(function(event) {
      console.log(event);
      $(this).fadeOut(3000);
    });
  });
  todos.splice(index, 1);
  set(todos);
  showList();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle with your html code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you display all items everytime you add a Todo is added or deleted but
another approach to do this is to do the following:

1. When adding a todo, add an `li` element to the current list with `style="display:none"` then call `fadeIn`
2. When deleting a todo, use `$('body').on()` event handler. For example `$("body").on("click", ".delete-todo", function(){...})` so that you dont need to specify a click handler for delete everytime a todo is added.
3. When deleting a todo, first identify which element was clicked then find the closest `li` element(since the li element has the `display:none` style set when adding) then call `fadeOut()` for that element. And when the fade out animation completes, remove the element.

Here's a sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/58tse0j4/. I hope it can help you. Usually we do data-binding for these stuffs but this example is only limited for jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will rewrite my code similar to yours.

Comment: I'm glad it helps. Maybe you can "Accept" the answer if possible. Thank you.